# EF6 not always generating FK references

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using **Entity Frameworks 6** and when I **reverse engineer** my schema from the database, I am finding that several FK relationships are not being generated.  It's driving me nuts.  If I add them in by hand I start getting key violation errors when trying to insert.  Take them back out and everything works fine.

Schema:  [image: DB Schema]

When I look at my RemarketingCase object I do not see any collections for Addresses, Debtors or Notes and no reference to Asset or Summary.  Yet, when I look at either Status objects I have an ICollection of RecordHistories/CaseHistories.  I look at either History tables and I have reference to the Status table but no reference to the RemarketingCase table.

This is really irksome as I am trying to deal with object graphs that just don't exist!  It is forcing me to handle the add of a RemarketingCase and all it's relationships by doing so one at a time, in the correct order so SQL does not pop a referential integrity error.

Sample with FK reference (generated by EF):

```
public partial class Status
{
    public Status()
    {
        this.CaseHistories = new List<CaseHistory>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CaseHistory> CaseHistories { get; set; }
}
public class StatusMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Status>
{
    public StatusMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(15);

        this.Property(t => t.Description)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Status");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
    }
}
```

Sample without FK reference(s) as generated by EF:

```
public partial class RemarketingCase
{
    public int LoanId { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string VIN { get; set; }
    public int RemarketingCaseId { get; set; }
    public string CaseId { get; set; }
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Updated { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
public class RemarketingCaseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<RemarketingCase>
{
    public RemarketingCaseMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.LoanId, t.RequestId, t.VIN });

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.LoanId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.RequestId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.VIN)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(25);

        this.Property(t => t.RemarketingCaseId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(t => t.CaseId)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.CaseNumber)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.AssetId)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.UpdatedBy)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("RemarketingCase");
        this.Property(t => t.LoanId).HasColumnName("LoanId");
        this.Property(t => t.RequestId).HasColumnName("RequestId");
        this.Property(t => t.VIN).HasColumnName("VIN");
        this.Property(t => t.RemarketingCaseId).HasColumnName("RemarketingCaseId");
        this.Property(t => t.CaseId).HasColumnName("CaseId");
        this.Property(t => t.CaseNumber).HasColumnName("CaseNumber");
        this.Property(t => t.AssetId).HasColumnName("AssetId");
        this.Property(t => t.Created).HasColumnName("Created");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
        this.Property(t => t.Updated).HasColumnName("Updated");
        this.Property(t => t.UpdatedBy).HasColumnName("UpdatedBy");
    }
}
```

Sample of hand adding references:

```
public partial class RemarketingCase
{
    public RemarketingCase()
    {
        this.Addresses = new List<Address>();
        this.Debtors = new List<Debtor>();
        this.Notes = new List<Note>();
        this.RecordHistories = new List<RecordHistory>();
        this.CaseHistories = new List<CaseHistory>();
    }

    public int LoanId { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string VIN { get; set; }
    public int RemarketingCaseId { get; set; }
    public string CaseId { get; set; }
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Updated { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    // manually added...
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Debtor> Debtors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecordHistory> RecordHistories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CaseHistory> CaseHistories { get; set; }
    public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }
    public virtual Summary Summary { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the error I get when I hand add the FKs:

> Test method AutoPay.Test.Remarketing.DatabaseChange.InsertAsset threw
>   exception:  System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An
>   error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error
>   occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A dependent property
>   in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column.
>   Column: 'RemarketingCaseId'.

Comment: The cause is simple: EF only accepts foreign key associations to full primary keys and *real* primary keys. Not unique constraints. This may be salvageable if `RemarketingCaseId` is unique and you can tell EF it's the primary key in the model.

Comment: I changed the PK and regenerated the models.  Still no FK showing up.  Will play with it more on Friday.

Comment: If you can change the model, just give each table a singular surrogate key, preferably an identity column. Much easier. For the rest, use unique indexes for column combinations that should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the DB design a bit, adding the dreaded ID field as the PK, this error went away.  While this is a violation of SQL normalization it is what it is.  Unfortunately, I've not found a way to make EF deal with a compound PK correctly.  (See the comments to my question.)